# Software stack for convention based ASP.NET MVC development

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, conventions

Besides ASP.NET MVC's obvious conventions, what libraries do you take advantage of that minimize boot strapping, mapping objects, data access and such?  I want to spend more energy developing domain logic as opposed to dealing with the details of object persistence (for example).

I have used StructureMap and NHibernate in the past to great effect.  Are there other tools or other libraries I should consider that further streamline the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write own core of project using:

- NHibernate - data access
- StructureMap - IoC, bootstrapping
- ...

that like you want or simply use one:

[S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this example: http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/ (it is based on S#arp Architecture framework). I haven't actually tried it but I do use a lot of the mentioned libraries myself, and it got very good feedback in S#arp google groups.

Answer (score 0):

We are very, very happy users of Autofac, NHibernate + FluentNHibernate :-) 
But to switch from StructureMap to Autofac or vice verca does not make difference. 
One of the next libraries I like to check out is AutoMapper.

FluentNHibernate + Schema generation is very worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective and from long-time experience at .NET & .NET Core projects I recommend:

- [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/ef/core/) for DAL (MS), sure with **code-first** (Microsoft)
- [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) for copy and move data across **DAL** & **BLL**
- [FluetValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) for **check** Input data, **validation**

together with:

- [Dependecy injection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) for better architecture and solving using application services (Microsoft)
- [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) for logging and running diagnostics